# Calculating an Average across multiple columns in Hadoop Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am trying to calculate an average of three columns in Hive but with no luck. Below is my code.

```
select c.university_name, c.country, AVG(c.world_rank) as AvgC, AVG(s.world_rank) as AvgS, AVG(t.world_rank) as AvgT, SUM(AvgC+AvgS+AvgT)/3 as TotalAvg 
from cwur c 
    join shanghai s on (c.university_name = s.university_name and c.year = s.year) 
    join times t on  (c.university_name = t.university_name and c.year = t.year)
```

Is Hive even capable of averaging across three calculated columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the group by clause

```
select 
      c.university_name, 
      c.country, 
      AVG(c.world_rank) as AvgC, 
      AVG(s.world_rank) as AvgS, 
      AVG(t.world_rank) as AvgT, 
      (AvgC+AvgS+AvgT)/3 as TotalAvg 
from cwur c 
join shanghai s on (c.university_name = s.university_name and c.year = s.year) 
join times t on  (c.university_name = t.university_name and c.year = t.year)
group by c.university_name, c.country
```